# sorting procedure of an array doesn't work - Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, sorting, excel

I am working on the following code, which is supposed to get the values from a spreadsheet into arrays, sort them (it's a triple sort here - three arrays are sorted at once), and finally place the results in another sheet...

The problem is I get a Subscript out of range" error message and I really don't know how to fix it 
I seem to have this problem EACH time I try sorting an array.. so there must be something wrong with the Sort ... (it is called TriFonds here)

Any help will be greatly appreciated..

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Class()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

Dim nb_Actions As Long


With Worksheets("Actions")
    nb_Actions = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With

ReDim NomAction(nb_Actions) As Double
ReDim IndiceAction(nb_Actions) As Double
ReDim Ratio(nb_Actions) As Double

With Worksheets("Actions")
'I fill in arrays with data from the column
        For i = 1 To nb_Actions
            Ratio(i) = .Cells(18 + i, 2).Value
        Next i


        For j = 1 To nb_Actions
            IndiceAction(j) = .Cells(18 + j, 3).Value
        Next j


        For k = 1 To nb_Actions
            NomAction(k) = .Cells(18 + k, 1).Value
        Next k
End With

        Call TriFonds(Ratio(), NomAction(), IndiceAction())



With Worksheets("Performance")
    For i = 1 To nb_Actions
        .Cells(4 + i, 2) = IndiceAction(i)
        .Cells(4 + i, 3) = NomAction(i)
        .Cells(4 + i, 4) = Ratio(i)
    Next i
End With
End Sub

Sub TriFonds(Tab1() As Double, Tab2() As Double, Tab3() As Double)
Dim Temp1 As Double
Dim Temp2 As Double
Dim Temp3 As Double
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim ligne_Fin As Long

'Last line from the sorting procedure
ligne_Fin = UBound(Tab1)

For i = 2 To ligne_Fin
    Temp1 = Tab1(i)
    Temp2 = Tab2(i)
    Temp3 = Tab3(i)

    For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1 'Increasing order
        If (Tab1(j) <= Temp1) Then GoTo 10
            Tab1(j + 1) = Tab1(j)
            Tab2(j + 1) = Tab2(j)
            Tab3(j + 1) = Tab3(j)

    j = 0


10    Tab1(j + 1) = Temp1
    Tab2(j + 1) = Temp2
    Tab3(j + 1) = Temp3
Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redimension the array variables, the value of `nb_Actions` is zero. So, you have declared array variables with base zero, and then you go to assign values to them starting with `For i = 1 to ...` which will cause an out of range type error.

Move these lines:

```
ReDim NomAction(nb_Actions) As Double
ReDim IndiceAction(nb_Actions) As Double
ReDim Ratio(nb_Actions) As Double
```

Beneath these lines:

```
With Worksheets("Actions")
    nb_Actions = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

**Update**

After downloading the file, I identify a mismatch declaration in the `TriFonds` subroutine.

You have declared `Temp2 as Double` but you are trying to assign string values from `Tab2() As String) to this variable.  This is causing the mismatch:

`Temp2 = Tab2(i)`

because you cannot put a Double value in a string variable.

**Update 2**  You have delcared `Temp3 as Double` but you are passing `Integer` data type. On my computer (Win 7 XP/Excel 2010) this does not cause an error, as an Integer can be passed to a Double variable. I suspect there is a quirk in Excel for Mac which does not allow this behavior.

**This revision executes without error on my computer and incorporates changes to the data type of `Temp2` and `Temp3`**:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub Class()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer

    Dim nb_Actions As Long

    With Worksheets("Actions")
        nb_Actions = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    ReDim NomAction(nb_Actions) As String
    ReDim IndiceAction(nb_Actions) As Integer
    ReDim Ratio(nb_Actions) As Double

    With Worksheets("Actions")
    'I fill in arrays with data from the column
            For i = 1 To nb_Actions
                Ratio(i) = .Cells(18 + i, 2)
            Next i


            For j = 1 To nb_Actions
                IndiceAction(j) = .Cells(18 + j, 3)
            Next j


            For k = 1 To nb_Actions
                NomAction(k) = .Cells(18 + k, 1)
            Next k
    End With

            Call TriFonds(Ratio(), NomAction(), IndiceAction())

     With Worksheets("Performance")
        For i = 1 To nb_Actions
            .Cells(4 + i, 2) = IndiceAction(i)
            .Cells(4 + i, 3) = NomAction(i)
            .Cells(4 + i, 4) = Ratio(i)
        Next i
    End With


End Sub

Sub TriFonds(Tab1() As Double, Tab2() As String, Tab3() As Integer)
    Dim Temp1 As Double
    Dim Temp2 As String   '## changed data type ##
    Dim Temp3 As Integer  '## changed data type ##
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ligne_Fin As Long

    'Last line from the sorting procedure
    ligne_Fin = UBound(Tab1)

    For i = 2 To ligne_Fin
        Temp1 = Tab1(i)
        Temp2 = Tab2(i)
        Temp3 = Tab3(i)

        For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1 'Increasing order
            If (Tab1(j) <= Temp1) Then GoTo 10
                Tab1(j + 1) = Tab1(j)
                Tab2(j + 1) = Tab2(j)
                Tab3(j + 1) = Tab3(j)

        j = 0


10        Tab1(j + 1) = Temp1
        Tab2(j + 1) = Temp2
        Tab3(j + 1) = Temp3
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How do I do that?

Btw, there is no longer any error. Now it just return ZEROs everywhere :(

Comment: I do not understand. Are you still getting the error, as you indicate 18 minute ago? If there is no error message being raised, then there is no error, and undesired results (e.g., zeros everywhere) will require you to debug and revise your logic.

Comment: You're going to have to tell me what line is raising the error.  When you get the error message, select the option to debug. Which line is highlighted???

Comment: These lines:    With Worksheets("Actions")
        nb_Actions = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    
    ReDim NomAction(nb_Actions) As Double
    ReDim IndiceAction(nb_Actions) As Double
    ReDim Ratio(nb_Actions) As Double
    
    With Worksheets("Actions")
    'I fill in arrays with data from the column
            For i = 1 To nb_Actions
                Ratio(i) = .Cells(18 + i, 2).Value
            Next i

Comment: All the lines from With Worksheets("Actions") down to the Next i after Ratio

Comment: I uploaded the worksheet here http://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/920662-help-needed-with-a-sorting-procedure-on-an-array-subscript-out-of-range.html?p=3226788#post3226788

Comment: I do not have permission to access that page. Try putting it on Google Docs or Dropbox or some other website where I do not need to create an account and have a certain amount of reputation in order to download the file.

Comment: If the error really happens on the line `With Worksheets("Actions") ` then please check to make sure that a Worksheet named "Actions" exists in the Active Workbook at runtime.

Comment: Please try uploading the file to Google Docs or Dropbox so that I can view it.

Comment: Just did it. https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bwjh7B2eKQEQWGxhZGt6WGlSalk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: OK. The error is happening in the `TriFonds` function. Give me a few minutes I will try to figure this out.

Comment: You declare `Temp2` as Double, but you are passing array variable `Tab2() as String`. That's causing a mismatch. Change the declaration to `Dim Temp2 as String`.

Comment: I did that but I still get subscript out of range. DId this work for you?

Comment: Try `Dim Temp3 as Integer`?

Comment: It kind of worked. Except now it gives the same two sets of values for the whole thing :S I'm going to try to see how to fix that.. it's probably a problem how I declare my function...

Comment: Well, if it's not throwing an error, then it *is* working, and the problem will be in the logic of your `TriFonds` subroutine.  Please consider upvoting or marking this "accepted" if it has resolved the scope of the immediate problem (mismatch/out of range errors).

If you have further problems troubleshooting your logic, please post as a new question.

Comment: Please avoid extended discussion in comments. Since this question already has an answer, please consider posting a new question. Use the debugger to step through your code and identify the line which raises the error.  Then, describe the error and what line causes it in the new question.